# VB disable "|" key

Tags: vb.net, keydown

I'm trying to disable the | key in a textbox as my csv file uses the character as a separator. However, I tried many methods and searched on google but I can't find any solutions related to that.

My code:

```
    Private Sub txtRemarks_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtRemarks.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Shift And e.KeyCode = AscW(220) Then
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Wonder if that is possible? Thanks

Comment: How can `KeyCode` be equal to two different values at the same time? Logic fail.

Comment: When I change that to e.KeyCode = AscW(220) only it still doesn't work

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You need to detect the `Shift` modifier and that key. Did you research how to do that? Apparently not.

Comment: Maybe a bit picky, but a csv file is "comma separated values"  as in the separator is a comma, not a "|".  You may cause issues at the other end if you present this as a csv when it is in fact not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect a key in combination with one or more modifiers then there are multiple ways to do it. You could do this:

```vb
Private Sub txtRemarks_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtRemarks.KeyDown
    If Not e.Control AndAlso e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Oem5 Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

or this:

```vb
Private Sub txtRemarks_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtRemarks.KeyDown
    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Oem5 Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but my preference would be this:

```vb
Private Sub txtRemarks_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtRemarks.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Oem5) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that that third snippet uses `KeyData` rather than `KeyCode`. The latter is just the current key while the former is the current key and any modifier keys.

If you want to make it a little more succinct:

```vb
Private Sub txtRemarks_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtRemarks.KeyDown
    e.SuppressKeyPress = (e.KeyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Oem5))
End Sub
```